# Return Cell address with Substring Match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I currently have a formula that checks a dataset for a sub-string and it returns the row number of the cell if it matches.

```
=IFERROR(SMALL(IF(Sheet1!B:B=E1,ROW(Sheet1!B:B)),ROWS(E$1:E1)),"")
```

Is there a way I can return the ***cell Address*** rather than just the row?

**For Example:** B14 rather than just 14.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: To what end, is the end product or are you going to use it in another formula?  If you are going to use it in another formula just Use Index with the column of the desired value with your current formula to return the proper row.

Comment: Look at the `ADDRESS` worksheet function

Comment: Tried changing to address but can't seem to get it working. Sorry if this just looks completely wrong {=CELL("address",INDEX($B$1:$B$500,SMALL(IF(($B$1:$B$500="Location")*($B$1:$B$500),""),3),1))}